# Can I use "PeriodicTask" and "ResourceIntensiveTask" together in one app on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

As the subject said, can I use `PeriodicTask` and `ResourceIntensiveTask` together in one app on Windows Phone?

Example, may I have a `PeriodicTask` and a `ResourceIntensiveTask` in same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. According to [How to: Implement Background Agents for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202941%28v=vs.92%29.aspx):

> Each application can have only one ScheduledTaskAgent registered at a time, but you can schedule this agent
>   as both a resource-intensive agent and a periodic agent. If your application uses both a ResourceIntensiveTask and a
>   PeriodicTask, you can check the type of the ScheduledTask object that is passed into the OnInvoke method to determine
>   for which task the agent is being invoked and branch your code execution as necessary.

You should be able to call ScheduledActionService.Add() on both kinds of tasks.